# Each Time Java Compile Warning

Tags: java

Whatever program i compile in java ( even the smallest program), just the hello world, but when i compile the program, it says -

warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'com.microsoft.azure.management.apigeneration.LangDefinitionProcessor' less than -source '12'

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: You know that a warning is just a warning and not an exception, right? It means that your annotation processor was compiled against an older version of java (1.7) vs your installed version of Java (12). It's odd, however, that you're getting warnings from Azure with hello world. You should be more descriptive and tell us what you're doing and how you're doing it because there's probably a more serious problem underlying this warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Your default CLASSPATH includes the azure SDK for java. Either because you've explicitly added it to the environment variable CLASSPATH, or, because you're on a pretty old JDK and it still has an 'ext' directory and you put it there.

A global classpath is a bad idea; you can use java for wildly different things on the same system. Hence why 'ext' is deprecated and messing with CLASSPATH is not advised.

Undo it: Remove azure.jar or whatever it might be called from the ext dir, or, undo the classpath messup. It's certainly possible that you ran some 'azure installer' that did this to your system, in which case, hopefully the uninstaller would fix this.

If you're not sure how to do these things, share the OS you're using.

Comment: The Operating System Is : WINDOWS 10

Comment: class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

Comment: Earlier this issue was not there, I first had JRE 8 then, i migrated to JRE 12 and after than i setup Android Studio... after that i then installed NetBeans 8 - post which this WARNING has started appearning..

Comment: None of that changes the answer. Instructions about checking classpath are here: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: I have JAVA Folder In C:\Program Files\  --- And, within JAVA folder there are 2 more folders for JDK 8 and JDK 12 - apart from this, the C:\Program Files also has a folder called ANDROID STUDIO --- The ETC folder is found in multiples within each of these folders.. now, from where to remove the AZURE.JAR and when i search on the proper file name AZURE.JAR - the file is not found.... I have ensured that the CLASSPATH environment variable is correct.  now what ??